# start faye on cloudControl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye, cloudcontrol

Question:

Problem is similar to [Faye setup in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228665/faye-setup-in-production). Can't start Faye in staging on [CloudControl](http://www.cloudcontrol.com). 
Here is `faye.ru`:

```
require 'faye'
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
run faye_server
```

Here is `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p $PORT
faye: bundle exec thin start -R faye.ru -p 9292
```

Staging log:

```
11/21/14 12:27 PM Deploy ***** Deployed 09c2174cba4b14375779a5160ab7348a62a570b4 *****
11/21/14 12:27 PM Info Started GET "/" for 10.99.3.169 at 2014-11-21 10:27:02 +0000
11/21/14 12:27 PM Info Listening on 0.0.0.0:25143, CTRL+C to stop
11/21/14 12:27 PM Info Maximum connections set to 1024
11/21/14 12:27 PM Info Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
11/21/14 12:27 PM Deploy ***** Deployed 09c2174cba4b14375779a5160ab7348a62a570b4 *****
11/21/14 12:27 PM Info Started GET "/" for 10.94.134.23 at 2014-11-21 10:27:01 +0000
11/21/14 12:27 PM Info Listening on 0.0.0.0:12103, CTRL+C to stop
11/21/14 12:27 PM Info Maximum connections set to 1024
11/21/14 12:27 PM Info Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
```

And myapp.cloudcontrolapp.com is ok, **but I can't get myapp.cloudcontrolapp.com:9292/faye.js**

If I do start rails server localy with faye I got it ok:
1. rails s
2. `if Rails.env.development?
  Thread.new do
    system("rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production")
  end
end`
in initializer. 
The local log is:

```
Thin web server
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
Thin web server 
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

And localhost:9292/faye.js is ok, localhost:3000 is ok

Can someone point me how to start faye on cloudControl? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only web type processes are accessible from the outside and they have to listen on the port specified in $port. Just like your first line in the Procfile. If you want a second process to listen on a port and be accessible from the outside, you have to put that into a second app.

Comment: Thanks. There should be some deep reason for this, but your decision is quite acceptable.